# jQuery UI widgets (ie. Slider) and triggering their custom event handlers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, slider, jquery-ui-slider

If we bind a `click` event to a link as

```
$("linkSelector").click(function(){ ... });
```

then we can easily also force executing this event handler even though user didn't click the link.

```
$("linkSelector").click(function() { ... }).click();
```

But in my case I'm using jQuery **Slider widget** which has the `slide` event to which an event handler can be bound. I wonder how can we force execute its events programatically?

I've tried following but none of them works:

```
$("sliderSelector").slider({ slide: function(){ ... } }).slide();
$("sliderSelector").slider({ slide: function(){ ... } }).slider("slide");
$("sliderSelector").slider({ slide: function(){ ... } }).trigger("slide");
```

I know I could use a named function instead of an anonymous one, but I don't consider that a solution because I can call the function with whatever arguments I want while triggering `slide` event would provide correct values as set by the slider.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger a jQuery UI slider event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288824/trigger-a-jquery-ui-slider-event)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

This is the resulting code that actually triggers such event handler:

```
var s = $("sliderSelector").slider({ slide: function(evt, ui){ ... } });
s.slider("option", "slide").call(s, null, { values: s.slider("values") });
```

Make sure you provide those function parameters that you actually use in your event handler. In my case where I'm using a range slider I need `ui.values` parameter, so I'm creating such an object so my handler won't break.

It's not a nice solution since I have to call `.slider()` function multiple times but it's the safest way of preventing the use of *magic values*.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a very similar issue.

If you register your callbacks with `.bind()` (or `.on` for later versions of jQuery) instead of putting them into the initialiser you can then invoke them as expected with `.trigger()`.

It seems that the two sorts of handlers are different, but I can't find that documented anywhere.