# Using the jQuery UI Slider to control layer opacity in OpenLayers

Tags: jquery-ui, openlayers

I asked my question on gis.stackexchange.com because of its geo nature, but I figured I would have a larger response here. https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/18327/3773

I have been trying to utilize the jQuery UI Slider to control layer opacity in OpenLayers but I have an issue when trying to set the "value" option to anything other than the "max" value.

What I would like to see is the setOpacity method change my layer's opacity to 20% onload. However, the slider is shown in the correct position but the layer displays the "max" value of opacity (100%/opaque).

I need to force the webpage to setOpacity onload, but I am not familiar on how to do this.

Removed the any unnecessary code. Your help is much appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-10592586.767623,5113378.756775,-8275939.536344,7731361.313701)};

    function init(){
        OpenLayers.ImgPath = "http://js.mapbox.com/theme/dark/";

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-10592586.767623,5113378.756775,-8275939.536344,7731361.313701),
            maxResolution:"auto",
            units:'m',
            controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({dragPanOptions: {enableKinetic: true}})
                ]
            });

        hii_1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("HII","http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe",{
            map:'C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/hii/hii_landcover.map'},{
            isBaseLayer:false,
            transparent:true,
            format:"image/png",
            alpha:true
            });

        osm_mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap: Mapnik");

        gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Maps: Streets");

        map.addLayers([hii_1,osm_mapnik,gmap]);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-9434263,6422370),5);
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    value: 20,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
        hii_1.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
        $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.value );
    }
    });
    $("#amount1" ).val($( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) );
</script>
```

Comment: Answered here:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/using-the-jquery-ui-slider-to-control-layer-opacity-in-openlayers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback of the slider is not called onLoad. To trigger the event manually, see [Trigger a jQuery UI slider event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289096/567083) for an example.

Though, it would be better to your layer with an opacity of 0.20. You can achieve that by adding the property opacity to your layers options.

`{
  isBaseLayer:false,
  transparent:true,
  format:"image/png",
  alpha:true,
  opacity:0.20
}`
.