# Why doesn't $("#slider").trigger("slide") result in calling the slide handler?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery slider (actually, a custom extension thereof) equipped with a handler for the `slide` event, and this handler gets properly called when the slider is manipulated interactively, but not when I run

```
$("#slider").trigger("slide");
```

This command runs without error, but the `slide` handler does not get called.

Why is this?

Do I need to pass a different argument to trigger to cause the `slide` handler to be called?

EDIT: changed post's title to more closely reflect the question's motivation.

Answer (score 5):

**Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/fLnmN/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/F5ZCK/

Use `.bind` like I used in the demo. you can use `.on` as well like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u82Y5/

Some really helpful post here: [Trigger a jQuery UI slider event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288824/trigger-a-jquery-ui-slider-event)

This should fit your need, `:)`

**code**

```
$('.slider').slider().bind({
    change: function() {
       alert('change triggered');
    }
});

$('.slider').trigger('change');
```

**OR**

```
$('.slider').slider().on({
    change: function() {
       alert('change triggered');
    },
    slidechange: function() {
        alert('slide trigger');
    }
});

$('.slider').trigger('change');
$('.slider').trigger('slidechange');
```

Comment: Thanks!  I refrain from accepting this answer because I'm trying to minimize the number of ways to do this.  (Hence the very narrow/focused specificity of my question.)  I don't understand the difference between specifying the callbacks in the slider's constructor and specifying them afterwards with `bind`.  More precisely, I don't understand why there should be a difference between these two approaches to begin with.  I barely understand the former approach as it is, and I'd rather not make matters more difficult on myself by introducing yet another approach (the one that uses `bind`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason `trigger('slide')` doesn't work is because when you set your `slide` callback, the slider does *not* register a slide event with the DOM element. Instead, it delegates generic mouse events to the DOM element and then translates them into your callbacks internally.

Unfortunately, this leaves you to work around that API. Tats_innit's answer binds events directly to the DOM element, but they don't tie into the slider API. You'll have to call your callback function within these handler function.

If you have your callbacks accessible, you can call them directly, as follows:

```
$('#slider').slider({
  'slide': onSlide
}).on('slide', onSlide);
```

If you prefer to define the callback functions inline, you can retrieve them as follows:

```
$('#slider').slider({
  'slide': function(event, ui) { /* ... */ },
}).on('slide', function() {
  $(this).slider('option', 'slide').apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Needless to say this is painfully redundant, but again, it's a workaround.

On a side note, remember that triggering events individually skips over other events that would be called in succession when they come from the user. For example, triggering a `stop` event would miss the `slide` event that the user would generate as he is adjusting the slider. You might consider "justifying" the external event binding by creating a custom event that dispatches multiple events on your behalf (e.g., `$('#slider').trigger('setvalue')`).

Comment: still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined` because it's missing the ui argument

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to call slide callback directly,
but you should pass event (or null) and object with value if its used inside calback:

```
var $slider = $("#slider");
$slider.slider('option', 'slide').call($slider, null, {value:1});
```