# Cant set slider manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm trying to have a slider move to a set position but also activate a function in the place of console.log. but it returns nothing until the slider is moved

**javascript:**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){   
        $( function() {
            $("#CPU_GHz").slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                step: 0.1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount_GHz" ).val( "Faster Than: " + ui.value + " GHz" ) ;

            }, 
            change: function(event, ui ) {
                CPU_GHz = ui.value;
                console.log(CPU_GHz);
            }
        });
        $( "#amount_GHz" ).val( "Faster Than: " + $( "#CPU_GHz").slider( "value" ) + " GHz");

      });


            $('#CPU_GHz').val('5').change()
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>  
          <input type="text" id="amount_GHz" readonly style="border:0; color:#2c85c5; font-weight:bold;">
        </p>

        <div id="CPU_GHz"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the value on page load with this line :

```
$("#CPU_GHz").slider('value',6);
```

Then you can output the result with the line you already wrote :

```
$( "#amount_GHz" ).val( "Faster Than: " + $( "#CPU_GHz").slider( "value" ) + " GHz");
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwzm1qs0/1/)

```
$( function() {
  $("#CPU_GHz").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount_GHz" ).val( "Faster Than: " + ui.value + " GHz" ) ;

    }, 
    change: function(event, ui ) {
      CPU_GHz = ui.value;
      console.log(CPU_GHz);
    }
  });


    $("#CPU_GHz").slider('value',6);

  $( "#amount_GHz" ).val( "Faster Than: " + $( "#CPU_GHz").slider( "value" ) + " GHz");

});
```

Comment: that cant be controlled manually. tho i have tried changing that with a variable it still won't affect what's in the change function

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to: [Trigger a jQuery UI slider event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288824/trigger-a-jquery-ui-slider-event)

```js
$(function() {
  var cpu = $("#CPU_GHz").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount_GHz").val("Faster Than: " + ui.value + " GHz");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      CPU_GHz = ui.value;
      console.log(CPU_GHz);
    }
  });
  $("#amount_GHz").val("Faster Than: " + cpu.slider("value") + " GHz");
  cpu.slider('option', 'change')(null, {
    value: cpu.slider('value')
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="amount_GHz" readonly style="border:0; color:#2c85c5; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="CPU_GHz"></div>
```

I tried to do a few other things yet they didn't work as expected. I thought `.trigger("change")` might work, yet this is not a standard change event. So I checked http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change and then tried `.trigger("slidechange")`. This didn't trigger the function either.

There are two ways to do it. If you initialize slider with `value: 0` and then set the Value later, this will trigger `change`:

```
cpu.slider("option", "value", 5.0);
```

Or if you have a set Value already, which I would advise, you can also manually trigger it in a round about way:

```
cpu.slider('option', 'change')(null, {
  value: cpu.slider('value')
});
```

This is calling the `change` function and passing `event` and `ui` to it, mostly. It's enough to run. Since you're not really using `event` in this case, it's ok to send nothing. But the function needs to know what the new value will be sop we send an Object with that.

Hope that helps.