# jQuery UI range slider sorting mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sorting items with range slider on my listing page. I want to use mousewheel function for sorting items. How can I use mousewheel on my range slider?

```html
<c:if test="${not empty facetData and facetData.name eq 'Price'}">
  <c:set var="minAmount" value="0"> </c:set>
  <c:forEach items="${facetData.values}" var="facetValue">
    <c:set var="maxAmount" value="${facetValue.code}"> </c:set>
  </c:forEach>

  <input type="hidden" id="sliderMinValue" value="${minAmount}" />
  <input type="hidden" id="sliderMaxValue" value="${maxAmount}" />
  <div class="price-range-bottom">
    <span>${minAmount}</span>
    <span>${maxAmount}</span>
  </div>
</c:if>
```

```js
var sliderMinValue = parseInt($('#sliderMinValue').val());
var sliderMaxValue = parseInt($('#sliderMaxValue').val());

var minSelectedValue = sliderMinValue;
var maxSelectedValue = sliderMaxValue;

$("#slider-range-price").slider({
  range: true,
  min: sliderMinValue,
  max: sliderMaxValue,
  title: "dfsdf",
  values: [minSelectedValue, maxSelectedValue],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#range-price").val(currencyIso + " " + ui.values[0] + ".00" + " - " + currencyIso + " " + ui.values[1] + ".00");
    min = ui.values[0];
    max = ui.values[1];
    $("#amountMin").val(min);
    $("#amountMax").val(max);

    $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").first().html('<span class="slider-left-value">' + currencyIso + '&nbsp;' + min + '.00</span>');
    $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").last().html('<span class="slider-right-value">' + currencyIso + '&nbsp;' + max + '.00</span>');

  }

});

$("#range-price").val(currencyIso + " " + $("#slider-range-price").slider("values", 0) + ".00" + " - " + currencyIso + " " + $("#slider-range-price").slider("values", 1) + ".00");

});

$('#slider-range-price').mouseup(function() {
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);;
  if (location.href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
    var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "q").val(urlParams.get('q'));
    $('#advanceSearchFilter').append(input);
  }
  $('#advanceSearchFilter').submit();
});
```

How can I implement this to my slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the slider with the mouse wheel, you need to listen for the `wheel` event.

To get scrolling up to increase the position, you have to reverse the `deltaY`'s sign.

To get the slide function to run you need to do some jiggery pokery as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288824/trigger-a-jquery-ui-slider-event). What I ended up doing was creating a separate function that is called both for `slide` and `change`, as you can't trigger `slide`. Then trigger `change` in the `wheel` handler.

```js
function doSlide(event, ui)
{
  console.log('Put all the stuff you\'d want in the slide function in here');
}

$( function() {
    $('#slider').slider({slide: doSlide, change: doSlide});
    $('#slider').on('wheel', e => { 
      let s = $('#slider');
      let change = -e.originalEvent.deltaY;
      let value = s.slider('value');
      s.slider('value', value + change);
      s.trigger('change');
      e.preventDefault(); 
      return false;
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried on https://jsfiddle.net/5oqfbzat/ its runing but when ı implement my code its not running :/

Comment: @oerbas I see. The issue is with `slide` not being triggered when the position of the slider changes. I've updated the code to manage that.